# How to configure SBT to use Scala 2.8?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have Scala 2.8.0 installed and don't wish to use Scala 2.7. Whenever I try to use SBT, it begins downloading Scala 2.7.7. Even if I call it in a directory with a Scala 2.8 project. How to avoid this behaviour? There is no man page for SBT, neither I could find SBT configuration files in /etc or ~/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needs that for itself. SBT is written for 2.7, regardless of the version of Scala being used to compile projects under its management.

[SBT](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/) is a Google Code project, and is extensively documented there.

Comment: Yup, this is a pretty common question too. See http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool/browse_thread/thread/a5f5236195b1c4cd for example.

Comment: It should be also noted that it doesn't matter if there's Scala on the PATH or current directory or not -- unless told otherwise, SBT will always download the Scala to be used, and the version should be specified in the configuration file for the project.